# Diretório Download Android

Tags: android, arquivo, download

Olá, no meu app eu faço o download de um arquivo CSV, porém ele nunca aparece nos Downloads do smartphone, eu só consigo visualizar se for com o Gerenciador de Arquivos. E também quando tento passar o arquivo para o computador, eu não consigo achar o diretório que foi salvo. O path do arquivo é esse **/storage/emulated/0/Download/16hrs.csv**.
Como eu faço para mostrar o arquivo nos downloads do smartphone e como faço para pegar esse arquivo pelo computador? obg

```
private File getStorageDir(String fileName) {
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName);
}
File f = getStorageDir(fileName);
FileWriter mFileWriter = null;

mFileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath , true);
writer = new CSVWriter(mFileWriter,';',' ');

String[] dTitle = {"Academia","Data", "Turma","Aluno","Piscinas","Metros","Tempo"};

writer.writeNext(dTitle);
writer.close();
mFileWriter.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Para pegar o caminho correto da pasta de downloads do android use o seguinte código:

```
 File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```